# How to round symbolic expressions to N digits in Matlab

Tags: matlab, rounding, symbols

When you try rounding a symbolic expression to N digits you get the error messages below:

```
>> format long
>> syms x;
>> round(x, 10)
Error using sym/round
Too many input arguments.
>> round(vpa(pi), 10)
Error using sym/round
Too many input arguments.
```

So how do you make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how you do

```
>> syms x; N = 6;
>> round(pi*10^N)/vpa(10^N)

ans =

3.141593
>> round(x*10^N)/vpa(10^N)

ans =

0.000001*round(1000000*x)
```